# How could I differentiate same object with different ID using augmented reality in Unity (Android)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, image-recognition

Assume we have two apples of same size and color and when I scan those apples it should store the apple with different ID and if I again try to scan apple it should display that this particular apple with this ID if it is present.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You can not do that with any AR SDKs if that is what you are asking.

Comment: then what i can use

Comment: @MebinJoe ..used some sdks

Comment: @AliKanat what i should use

Comment: You need to implement some object recognition algorithms yourself

Comment: can we do this using ML @AliKanat ? ...  if suppose those apples are fixed at their location in room.. then can we differentiat them

Comment: Of course you can use ML. You can train your algorithm to recognize apples but it does not have to be at fixed locations. That is not necessary.

Comment: which algorithm i should use ? @AliKanat